# batch update in play-morphia

Tags: java, mongodb, playframework, morphia

I'm using Play framework 1.2.5 and Play-Morphia module.
I want to know if there's a way to update many objects at one Morphia query. I've found this example at https://github.com/greenlaw110/play-morphia/blob/master/documentation/manual/crud.textile, but it seems that I can't use "in" operation in norder to find all the objects which I hold in a list of their IDs.

I'm trying to update the paidInvoiceDocNum filed in each of the objects which their IDs are in the list "itemsIds". This is what I've tried so far:
String q = TransactionItem.find().field("id").in(itemsIds).toString();
TransactionItem.o().set("paidInvoiceDocNum", String.valueOf(docNumber)).update(q);

Without the .toString() it doesn't work either.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After long time of experimenting with Play-Morphia, I've found the way to do this update and here it is:

```
Datastore ds = TransactionItem.ds();
UpdateOperations<TransactionItem> op = ds.createUpdateOperations(TransactionItem.class).set("paidInvoiceDocNum", String.valueOf(docNumber));
Query<TransactionItem> q = (Query<TransactionItem>)TransactionItem.q().filter("id in", itemsIds).getMorphiaQuery();
ds.update(q, op);
```

Hope It will help...

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this?

```
TransactionItem.o().set("paidInvoiceDocNum", docNumber).update("id in", itemsIds);
```

BTW, what's your morphia version. Keep in mind Play has close the updates to modules. Use this to get the latest morphia plugin version: https://gist.github.com/greenlaw110/2868365

Comment: It didn't work... I've got this exception: com.google.code.morphia.query.ValidationException: The field 'in' could not be found in 'models.TransactionItem' while validating - in; if you wish to continue please disable validation.